# Numpy: how to select items in numpy and assign its value

Tags: python, list, numpy, for-loop, range

I have got a problem in assigning new value by list.

I want to change 12 items values in s numpy by numpy array's index ,and i hope every index i choose is different.
so i made a list random.sample(range(0,len(s),12) to select 12 different index.And through this index change some of values in numpy array s()
However, I'm getting the error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

```
    import numpy as np
    import random
    N = 20
    s = np.zeros([N])
    alist = random.sample(range(0,20),12)
    alist
    for i in alist:
       s(i)=10
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to achieve here, but `s(i)` is your problem: round brackets imply a function call, but `s` is a numpy array, so this won't work . I think you're trying to index the list, in which case you'd use `s[i]`.

Comment: I'm not to index the list.actually i want to change 12 items values s numpy by numpy array's index ,and i hope every index i choose is different.

Comment: It's still not totally clear to me, but maybe you're looking to change the for loop to `for i in range(len(alist)): s[i]=10`, but then it feels like I'm stabbing in the dark. It would be helpful if you could provide your expected output.

Comment: thanks again! e.g.`s=(1,2,2,4,5,6)`and i would like randomly  choose 3 in `s` by its subscript index.the output could be`s(0),s(1),s(3)` but could not  be like `s(0),s(1),s(1)`,means each of them subscript must be different.Then i change three of  them value from their orign value to 10.so `s(0)=10,s(1)=10,s(3)=10`.This is what i want.

Comment: so `alist=random.sample(range(0,len(s+1),3)` if the output is`alist=0,1,2` and i will choose s(0),s(1),s(2) to change their values.so use`for i in alist ` `s(i)= alist` `s(0)=10,s(1)=10,s(2)=10`